# Modify stage size cause error - Flash CC

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cc

I have an application with 2 scene, the first scene contains 4 movieclips which are placed manually into the scene, every movieClip had an instance name `(mc1,mc2..mc4),` and I create an array with this objects `var arr:Array = [mc1..mc4];` 
I add them an mouse event listener , for each (var i in arr){ i.addEvent...mouse.click)};

In this scene I also have an button "next scene" which have this code : `nextScene();`
In the second scene I have one button "back"  which have this code  : `prevScene();`
My app is 1200 x 720 px size, and I want it 800 x 600, so when I'm changing this manually .
When I'm running the application, everything is good, a go to next scene, and when I press back, it gives me an error  at first scene

```
for each(var i in arr){
 i.addEvent...mouse.click)
};

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Main/frame2()
    at flash.display::MovieClip/prevScene()
    at Main/onBack()
```

When I trace mc1 , at first run scene1 the output is //movieclip
when I'm pressing back the output is  // null
and if I trace arr, the output is //   ,movieclip,movieclip,movieclip (first only comma)
what can be the problem? thank you

Scene 1 code:

```
stop();
trace(mc1); // first run -> object [MovieClip]
           // when back pressd -> null


var selectedIm:MovieClip = mc1;
var selectedD = d1; 
var difficulty:uint = 3;
var imgs:Array = [mc1,mc2,mc3,mc4];
var diff:Array = [d1,d2,d3,d4];

goBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onGo);

for each(var i in imgs){
    i.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onImage); //here is the error, NULL OBJECT
}

function onGo(e:MouseEvent):void{ //next button
    new Clk().play();
    nextScene();
}

function onImage(e:MouseEvent):void{
    new Clk().play();
    if(selectedIm) selectedIm.filters = [];
    selectedIm = e.target as MovieClip;
    addOutline(selectedIm,0xFFFFFF,6); 
}
```

...

Scene 2 code:

```
...
    function onBack(e:MouseEvent):void{
    new Clk().play();
    removeChild(pz);
    timer.reset();
    timer.stop();
    timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, numara);
    prevScene();
  ....
```

}

Comment: Do you create the mcs with code, or are they on the timeline?

Comment: they are on the timeline, I put them manually.

Comment: I'd say drop scenes period, use container MCs instead.